# Can AngularJS select directive have more than one null option?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have Angular select directive with ng-options. Also I have one null option:

```
<select ng-model="selected_company.current" ng-options="company.name for company in subcontractors">
    <option value="">Please select a company...</option>
</select>
```

But I would like to have another null option at the end of the list so the resulting list would be:

- Please select a company...
- Company1
- Company2
- Company3
- Company4
- New company...

I've tried with:

```
<select ng-model="selected_company.current" ng-options="company.name for company in subcontractors">
    <option value="">Please select a company...</option>
    <option value="">New company...</option>
</select>
```

But as you can guess nothing happens, second null option doesn't show anywhere. Is there some Angular way around this? I know that one alternative would be ng-repeating option elements instead of using ng-options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution would be that I add another element to your original array:

In controller

```
$scope.companies = $scope.subcontractors + [{name: 'New company...'}]
```

in html

```
<select ng-model="selected_company.current" ng-options="company.name for company in companies">
    <option value="">Please select a company...</option>
</select>
```

Or even better would be you only modify the html to the following

```
<select ng-model="selected_company.current" ng-options="company.name for company in subcontractors + [{name: 'New company...'}] ">
    <option value="">Please select a company...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, I just tried that and it works well. Since I need to execute a function on clicking that last item I need to handle it. Which is not a big of a problem but I just wondered if Angular has some kind of ability to add more null elements that I'm not aware of. But thanks for input.

Comment: I guess there is not any better way to handle the problem. If you have a function to be executed on ng-change, the task you want to achieve will be trivial. It will check the value of selected_company.current.name and if it is equal to 'New company...' it can take the right action